# How do I authenticate using requests for google drive v3 api calls

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use requests in python with the google drive api v3.  I can get my script to authenticate and run calls with a service.  But I notice that most of the documentation for API V3 shows examples using http requests under the "reference" tab.  When I try to complete a call using requests, I'm not sure how to put my Oath 2.0 authentication in to reference the token.pickle.  Tried to force the token to a string but did not work.  The whole script is below.  You can see the "#delete mp4File" section is where I'm trying to create a request and add authentication.  This is where I need help.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import os
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
import requests

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
          ]

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # List contents of mp4 folder
    results = service.files().list(
        q="'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' in parents", pageSize=1).execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        for item in items:
            mp4File=(u'{0}'.format(item['id']))
            mp4Name=(u'{0}'.format(item['name']))
            print (mp4Name + " " + mp4File)

    # Download mp4File
    file_id = mp4File
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.FileIO(mp4Name, 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

    #delete mp4File
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id

    headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(token)
                }

    response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers)

    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `When I try to complete a call using requests, I'm not sure how to put my Oath 2.0 authentication in to reference the token.pickle.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? For example, is [Quickstart for python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) useful?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes! I'd be happy to expand on this in detail.  I created a project and gave it the scopes to download, delete and edit files on gdrive.  I grabbed the authentication code from the quickstart to get a token.  I used to token for a couple of previous api calls to list files and download them.  Now I want to delete the file that I downloaded.  When I look up documentation for this, it just provides an DELETE url http call for drive v3.  So I am trying to use requests to execute this call.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about your current issue and your goal.

Comment: What scope are you using in you application? If it is a read-only scope, then you will need to delete your `token.pickle` file and reauthenticate, as the quickstart only provides a read-only scope in its example.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, I updated my post and included the scopes for you to see.  My token.pickle includes these scopes.  My basic problem is how to show the token.pickle in a request header to authenticate my call.  Tanaike, I updated the wording of my post, let me know if that makes it more clear?  Thanks for your help, both of you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to delete a file in Google Drive using `requests` with python.
- Your `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)` can be used for deleting the file.

#### Modification point:

- In your script, the access token can be retrieved by `creds.token`.

When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(token)
```

To:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + creds.token
```

#### Other pattern:

When googleapis for python is used like `service.files().list()`, it becomes as follows.

```
service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

#### Note:

- The method of "Files: delete" in Drive API returns no values. So please be careful this.

  > If successful, this method returns an empty response body.

#### Reference:

- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)